# Как изменить шрифт в activity в android?

Tags: android

Как можно добиться изменения шрифта во всём activity или хотя бы во всех TextView данного activity?

Comment: А как Вы пытались это сделать и что не получилось?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource